# Flutter - start foreground service on boot

Tags: android, flutter, package, naming, foreground-service

I'm trying to start a foreground service in flutter upon boot.
To achieve this I'm using [flutter_foreground_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_foreground_plugin)
I added a BOOT_COMPLETED receiver to the android's app manifest, and the broadcast receiver is being called properly, and I can run code inside it upon boot.
My problem is really simple - I cannot seem to find the proper name for the  changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin.FlutterForegroundService plugin to start it via an intent.
NOTE that the package name of the foreground plugin is of course different from mine.

Here's the relevant extract from AndroidManifest:

```
<receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".ServiceStartup" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name="changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin.FlutterForegroundService"/>
```

And here's the code of Service Startup:

```
package com.somecompany.myapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;

public class ServiceStartup extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>> In onReceive of ServiceStartup <<<<<<< ");
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent intent = new Intent("changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin.FlutterForegroundService");
                intent.setPackage("changjoopark.com.flutter_foreground_plugin");
                context.startForegroundService(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried all possible combinations of specifying the package name & component, neither seems to work, for all I get an error in logcat of unable to find component.
What am I missing? How should I start the service?

Thanks!

Comment: where you able to resolved this issues, i'm actually having a similart problem

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but answering it here for any future reader.

only `context.startForegroundService(intent);` will not start service as the package is doing more than just `startForegroundService`

Check the `launchForegroundService` method in class `FlutterForegroundPlugin`

`launchForegroundService` does `startForegroundService` and then `startServiceLoop`

On BOOT_COMPLETE event you need to call `launchForegroundService`. But its a private function.

so perform all operations done by launchForegroundService in your broadcast receiver .